# When I select a REAL datatype from SQL using PDO, the number is altered

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I thought I had seen this addressed but I cannot find it after 2 hours of googling.

I have a REAL data type in my database, I stored the value 0.00054

When I select it in SQL studio, I get 0.00054 no problem.

When I select it in php using pdo, I get 0.00053999998

Here is from SQL studio also:

```
select val_real, convert(decimal(38,18),val_real) from myTable
```

result: `0.00054, 0.000539999979082490`

From PHP using PDO result:

```
5.3999998E-4, .000539999979082490
```

It looks like php is converting the type before I can get to it. I am pulling my hair out. How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: 0.00053999998 seems pretty close to 0.00054 if you ask me. The SQL in fact has the same value as your PHP result, so this is all normal.

Comment: Haha, yes, it is very close, the problem is this is a user entered number and it must match what they type in, not change their number.

Comment: In that case, use a string or decimal, not a real.

Comment: Question is... why do you even use real data type

Comment: You are right. This will be used for a calculation but I can just convert it in PHP when I need to. I overlooked the simplest solution. Maybe I had too much coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP isn't converting anything, as also proven by your SQL query:

```
select val_real, convert(decimal(38,18),val_real) from myTable

result: 0.00054, 0.000539999979082490
```

The problem is that the value `0.00054` cannot be accurately represented using a real, so you get the closest value to it, which is `0.000539999979082490`.

Read this: http://floating-point-gui.de/ for more information.

If you need to store data verbatim from what a user enters, use a string type or a decimal if you want numbers.

Comment: Why can I see 0.00054 in SQL studio buy not via PHP PDO? The data type in SQL is REAL, so why can it show 0.00054 when I select it?

Comment: When I select the real data type from SQL Studio it gives 0.00054 how can it do that if real cannot represent it properly?

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you? To represent the data as `0.00054`, you will have to round it, apparently SQL Studio does that for you.

Comment: I read it, but how does SQL studio know how many decimal places to round to? How does it know I didn't actually want to store 0.000539999999

Comment: It *did* store `0.000539999999`, as proven when you cast it to a `DECIMAL(38, 18)`. I don't know the default rounding of SQL Studio, but it might just be 5 numbers. That this is the same as what your client input, is purely coincidental.

Comment: Interesting, I just did a test where I tried to update a real to 0.00059999999 and it change it to 0.00054! You are right!

Comment: I think you meant `0.000539999999`, and it didn't change it. It is the way it is represented.

Comment: No I mean I typed 0.000539999999 into SQL studio into a real type column using "edit top 200 rows" and it immediately displayed 0.00054